# How to use a javascript namespace?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, titanium

I have aes.js and aesctr.js in the same folder with my FirstWindow.js and I stumped on how to use those namespaces.

If we dont actually use a (psuedo code) #include namespace, then how does it actually get created?

My work:

```
aesctr = aesctr || {};
var aes = require('aes.js'); 
Titanium.include('aes.js')
Titanium.include('aesctr.js')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

See [this example](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/Coding_Strategies-section-29004891_CodingStrategies-Namespacedpatternwithselfcallingfunctions) of using a namespace pattern in Titanium.

Also, note that Appcelerator is recommending the use of [CommonJS](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/Coding_Strategies-section-29004891_CodingStrategies-CommonJSmodules) for code structure, and not global namespaces.  See more info on CommonJS best practices [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/Mobile_Best_Practices-section-29004793_MobileBestPractices-ApplicationsshallbemodularandobjectorientedusingCommonJSmodules).